# What kind of task will be done with the following code?

Tags: c++

What kind of task will be done with the following code ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int n, m;
    cin>>n;
    m = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {     
        m = m * 10 + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    cout<<m;
}
```

Comment: This code will be assigned as a learning exercise.

Comment: Try going through it on paper by hand.

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: I did, but only typed 1 number, the point was to type 2 or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program builds a new number reversing the order of decimal digits of the entered number. For example if 123 was entered then the result will be 321.

By the way why do not to compile it and see the result?:)

Answer (score 0):

So simple it is.
Why do not you compile it and see the result?

521 -> 125
789998122 -> 221899987

reverse order of the integer inputted.